# How to define and assign child element style in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, twilio, twilio-video

I want to show local video as fit in ReactJS App. And trying to width as 100%. But how to declare this style in React?

**React Component**

```
componentDidMount() {
  Video.createLocalVideoTrack().then(track => {
     const localMediaContainer = this.refs.localMedia;
     localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
  });
}

render () {
  return (
      <div ref='localMedia' />
  )
}
```

**The Result:**

```
<div>
  <video autoplay=""></video>
</div>
```

The video element is created by twilio track automatically (container.appenChild). And I want to define css style for this element.

**This works in HTML/JS:**

```
div#local-media {
      width: 100%;
      height: 220px;          
      margin: 0 auto;

  div#local-media video {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
```

**In React:**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    localMedia: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 220,         
        margin: '0 auto'

    }
});
```

How can I declare for child element, **div#local-media video** in react?

Or is there another solution to stretch media to local-media div?

**Update 1:**
 element generated by Twilio code with appendChild..

**Update 2**

I guess I found a solution? It's working

```
render() {
  return (
    <style jsx>{`
      video {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
    `}
    </style>

    <div ref='localMedia' />
  )
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing this 
`const styleVideo={width:'100%'}` and then adding this style to your video html
`<video style={styleVideo} autoplay=""></video>`

Comment: can you create a demo for that> https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: I'd like to create but Twilio Video api need to API ID, SID etc... I cant post these number on that place. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using styles and themes, from which I can expect you are using Material UI in react , then you should use the object `classes` as per the documentation (https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/).

So the code should be :

```
<div class={props.classes.localMedia}>
   <video autoplay=""></video>
</div>
```

you can try doing this.

Comment: Yes I'm using MateriaUI. localMedia style is working for div element but not the child element, video.